# Dblink to insert values i remote database with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to insert values of ABC into my_table in different DB connected via dblink  (both tables have the same columns but are unknown)

I have tried using record and cursors

```
 sql_str := 'select dblink_exec(''myconn'',''insert into my_table select * from abc'')';
 execute(sql_str);
```

error is abc table not found

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Maybe a typo? `exexute` to `execute`?